# ScrollTop issue -- moves to bottom first

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with scrollTop it seems like when clicking on the top element it first goes to the bottom then up. If I'm already at the bottom then it works fine. I'm trying to make it so it moves up from its current position

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 

</head>

<body> 
  <div class="container-full">
      
      <div class="navbar" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
         <div class="navbar-header">
         </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="box-label-container">
         
      </div>
     </div>

    <div class="container-full"> 
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
          <h4><a href="#project-section">projects</a></h4>
          <img src="images/project-diagram.png" alt="project diagram" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <h4><a href="#work-section">work</a></h4>
          <img src="images/working-wheels.png" alt="work=image" /> 
        </div>

         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <h4><a href="">me</a></h4>
          <img src="images/computer-guy-sketch.png" alt="work=image" /> 
         </div>
      
      </div>
    
    <a name="Projects" id="project-section">
 <div class="work" style="height:500px; background-color:#f8f8f8"><strong>Projects</strong></div></a>

 <a name="Projects" id="work-section">
 <div class="work" style="height:500px; background-color:#f8f8f8"><strong>work</strong></div></a>

    <footer>
     <a href="#top" id="top"><img src="images/up-arrow.png" alt="up-arrow" /> </a>
      <div class="social-icons">
     <a href=""><img src="images/github-icon.png" alt="github-icon" /></a>
     <a href-""><img src="images/linkedin-icon.png" alt="linkedin-icon" /></a>
     <a href=""><img src="images/twitter-icon.png" alt="twitter-icon" /></a>
      </div>
    </footer>
</div> <!-- /container full -->
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){ 
 $('a').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') )
          .offset().top}, 700);
     return false;
   });

  $("#top").click(function(e) {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 700);
     return false; });

});


</script>
```

Comment: hmm, the snippet seems to work fine for me using Chrome

Comment: it doesn't go to the bottom first? i'm using chrome as well

Comment: okay i pasted my entire file now and it doesn't work

Comment: haha yes its more obvious now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the other general `a` click event handler running first and scrolling to its `href` target before the `top`-specfic one. This means when you click `top`, it will scroll down to itself and then up to the top.

The best way to handle this is to have the `top` element at the top of the page, such as `<div class="container-full" id="top">` so that you don't need two different event handlers and it will work without javascript enabled.

If you want to keep it as-is, you just need to exclude `<a id="top">` from the general `a` event handler using `$('a[id!=top]').click(function(){...}`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 

</head>

<body> 
  <div class="container-full">
      
      <div class="navbar" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
         <div class="navbar-header">
         </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="box-label-container">
         <ul>
          <li>html</li>
          <li>css</li>
          <li>JS</li>
          <li>php</li>
          <li>java</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div class="container-full"> 
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
          <h4><a href="#project-section">projects</a></h4>
          <img src="images/project-diagram.png" alt="project diagram" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <h4><a href="#work-section">work</a></h4>
          <img src="images/working-wheels.png" alt="work=image" /> 
        </div>

         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <h4><a href="">me</a></h4>
          <img src="images/computer-guy-sketch.png" alt="work=image" /> 
         </div>
      
      </div>
    
    <a name="Projects" id="project-section">
 <div class="work" style="height:500px; background-color:#f8f8f8"><strong>Projects</strong></div></a>

 <a name="Projects" id="work-section">
 <div class="work" style="height:500px; background-color:#f8f8f8"><strong>work</strong></div></a>

    <footer>
     <a href="#top" id="top"><img src="images/up-arrow.png" alt="up-arrow" /> </a>
      <div class="social-icons">
     <a href=""><img src="images/github-icon.png" alt="github-icon" /></a>
     <a href-""><img src="images/linkedin-icon.png" alt="linkedin-icon" /></a>
     <a href=""><img src="images/twitter-icon.png" alt="twitter-icon" /></a>
      </div>
    </footer>
</div> <!-- /container full -->
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){ 
 $('a[id!=top]').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') )
          .offset().top}, 700);
     return false;
   });

  $("#top").click(function(e) {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 700);
     return false; });

});


</script>
```

Comment: That makes perfect logical sense -- I went with making one event handler and added the id top to it. Thank you for your time in helping me -- much appreciated